# Why does 'git merge' add files ending with tilde?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm in the process of merging two git branches that are fairly diverged.
After the automatic merge is complete, I ended up having multiple files having two versions:

```
file.cc~HEAD
file.cc~branchA
```

While the original `file.cc` was gone.
Since both files are identical, I'm slightly puzzled. Why does it happen? Which kind of conflict does it represent?

Comment: it's just a temp files with content for each branch. These files appear from your mege tool(vim for example). You can add igrnore rule *.*~

Comment: So why the original file was missing/deleted?

Comment: no $MERGED argument at merging

Comment: If you still need help with this, can you provide a simple example that duplicates this behavior?

Comment: Edward Thomson's answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204077/how-to-deal-with-xxxhead-after-git-merge

Comment: See `git clean` for cleaning these up.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that you are trying to merge two git branches that are fairly diverged. So in this situation, automatic merge fail.

Ideally, this situation occurs when your local file let say `file.cc` and file in the other branch in which you are merging are fairly diverged or lack any common ancestor so they cannot be merged. And then, we must keep both files in the working directory but as a conflict. So  `file.cc~HEAD` and `file.cc~branchA` files created and original file `file.cc` deleted.

For more information on `git merge` read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge) article.