# When rebasing, what are the files git shows with `~branchname` and `~HEAD` appended?

Tags: git, git-rebase, rebase

When rebasing a project, git showed me two curious untracked files:

```
example-file.yml~HEAD
example-file.yml~my-current-branch
```

Comparing the files showed their contents to be identical without any merge syntax.

**What are these files?** How are they created, and what is the difference between them?

Comment: Related (and also un-answered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863064/why-does-git-merge-add-files-ending-with-tilde

Comment: Git does not create these itself.  What merge assistant do you use?

Comment: @torek Gitolite, I believe; I can't find anything in their docs because `~` isn't searchable

Comment: Gitolite is a wrapper for controlling who can do what on a centralized server repository.  I've only used it a tiny bit (relatively long ago) but as far as I know it does not try to assist with merge, so I don't think that's it.