# How to deal with xxx~HEAD after git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

**In my branchA:**

I copy a file from `folder04/config.xml` to `folder05/config.xml`, then `git add` and `commit`.

**In my branchB (B is branch out from A):**

I already have one file named `folder05/config.xml`.

**Now I merge `branchA` into `branchB`, it appears a weird conflict like this.**

```
Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be
committed)

    folder05/config.xml~HEAD
```

It generates a file named config.xml~**HEAD**, what does it means?

I can't understand why, and what should I do in this situation?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; when I try there is a merge conflict in `config.xml` upon merging `branchA` into `branchB`. Can you provide details about how this happened? When was `folder05/config.xml` added to `branchB`? When did `branchB` branch off from `branchA`? Did `folder05` already exist then?

Comment: branchB added folder05/config.xml after it branch out from branchA, so before I commit folder05/config.xml in branchA, branchB already have that file.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this, but I would suspect that the untracked file `folder05/config.xml~HEAD` is the `branchB`-version of the file, while the real file (`folder05/config.xml`) is the one from `branchA`. Is this the case?

Comment: branchA version has more characters.

Comment: folder05/config.xml~HEAD is the branchB-version of the file <-- that make sense

Comment: @kowsky: it's a bit tricky to produce the problem (and it would have been helpful for Kuanlin Chen to have quoted the `CONFLICT (rename/add)` or whatever line), but see [Edward Thomson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48208268/1256452).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It generates a file named config.xml~HEAD, what does it means?

This file was generated automatically by `git` because you had a filename collision conflict - you had two items that were unrelated in the two branches trying to occupy the name `config.xml`.

This could be caused by a variety of situations:

**Most likely**, you created file named `config.xml` in your branch.  In the branch you're merging in, a different file was renamed *to* `config.xml`.  Since these two files lack any common ancestor, they can't be merged.  They should both be kept in the working directory, but as a conflict.  So they will *both* be kept, but with unique names.

The `config.xml` in the *branch being merged* will be checked out on disk as `config.xml`.  The `config.xml` in *your branch* will be checked out on disk as `config.xml~HEAD`.

Here's an example, where we add a file named `newname.txt` in our `master` branch, and rename `file.txt` into `newname.txt` in the branch that we're merging in.  In this case, a conflict will be raised and our branch's contents will be written as `newname.txt~HEAD` in the working folder:

```
% git checkout -bbranch
Switched to a new branch 'branch'

% git mv file.txt newname.txt

% git commit -m"rename file -> newname"
[branch d37e379] rename file -> newname
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename file.txt => newname.txt (100%)

% git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

% echo "new file" > newname.txt

% git add newname.txt

% git commit -m"added newname in master"
[master f7bd593] added newname in master
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 newname.txt

% git merge branch
CONFLICT (rename/add): Rename file.txt->newname.txt in branch. newname.txt added in HEAD
Adding as newname.txt~HEAD instead
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Once you have resolved the conflict to your satisfaction and committed the merge, you can simply delete the `~HEAD` file from your working directory.

(Finally, remember that git does not *track* that renames occurred, it uses heuristics to detect renames.  So this conflict - in practice - may not *really* be a conflict because the files may not have *really* been renamed.)

Comment: Clear explanation.

Comment: Reference: [developercommunity.visualstudio.com: ~HEAD files after rebase](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/308658/head-files-after-rebase.html)